# What are some ways to deploy an ASP.NET application to multiple EC2 instances?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have created an EC2 instance (called A), and want to test the open source NerdDinner on it.

After having created and RDS instance for my database and created a database, how can I deploy my NerdDinner to the A instance?

And after that, I want to create two other EC2 instances (B,C) that can run the same app with the same database. Is that what Load balancing is doing?

If I update the app, do I have to deploy the app each time on the three instances (A,B,C)?

Comment: Hey Steffen,do you have some ideas or experiences with that.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon Elastic Beanstalk will do all this for you.  The even have example documentation using the Nerd Dinner app as an example!

[Elastic Beanstalk .NET](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/05/net-support-for-aws-elastic-beanstalk-amazon-rds-for-sql-server-.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can try new cloud deployment tool [Appveyor](http://www.appveyor.com). It will script your database and deploy it to EC2 instances created on-the-fly. You can create new EC2 instances for web with Appveyor and use the same database instance.

Disclaimer: I'm Appveyor developer.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to deal loadbalancer configuration and manual deployments, you should take a look at [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) which automated all of this for you.

(Disclosure: I'm co-founder of [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/))